# CSS right align centered in <td>

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

[image: Align input fields]

How would I align the 3 input fields so that the right edges are all vertical?
I would still like the text+Input to be in the middle of the column but aligned vertically...

Currently using Bootstrap 3.3.7

HTML:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="table-responsive col-lg-12 ">
<table class="table table-bordered text-center">
    <thead>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th class="text-center" scope="row">Net. Config</th>
            <td>
                <form class="form-inline">
                    IP Address:
                    <input type="text" class="form-control txbIPsubmit" id="SYST_IPAD" placeholder="0.0.0.0">
                </form>
                <form class="form-inline">
                    NetMask :
                    <input type="text" class="form-control txbIPsubmit" id="SYST_NETM" placeholder="0.0.0.0">
                </form>
                <form class="form-inline">
                    Gateway :
                    <input type="text" class="form-control txbIPsubmit" id="SYST_GWAD" placeholder="0.0.0.0">
                </form>
                <div class="form-control-static">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="SYST_DHCP">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="SYST_DHCP">DHCP</label>
                </div>

                <form class="form-inline">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-light" id="btnNetConfig">Apply</button>
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: You should not use `table` structure for your form. And also you are creating `form` for each `input` which is bad. Use bootstrap's grid https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many things wrong (or at least, out of the standard and good practices) in that code.

**First**: you don't need to use one form tag for every field but only one wrapping the whole table

**Second**: it's not recommended to use table for this kind of content. There are many other ways to do this. Such as flexbox ([Basic concepts of flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox))
Tables are only recommended for when the information you have to display is an actual table. (a set of information in rows and columns)

**Third**: th tags are supposed to be used inside thead tags (h is for header, they are supposed to be the top cell for every column showing the title for the content in that column)

If you still want to use tables for this you should make a td for the label of the field and one for the input in every row, and you can use colspan and rowspan to make cells occupy the space of more than one cell (horizontally or vertically respectively) try this code:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="3">net. config</td>
        <td style="text-align:right;">IP Address</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="SYST_IPAD" placeholder="0.0.0.0"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align:right;">Netmask</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="SYST_NETM" placeholder="0.0.0.0"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align:right;">Gateway</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="SYST_GWAD" placeholder="0.0.0.0"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your problem and improve usability/accessibility in one shot. We can use a `flexbox` display on the `form`s to fix your alignment issues. I added `<label>`s to the text and set them `flex-grow: 1`. This tells the `<label>`s to take up maximum horizontal space. Another advantage is that it creates a second child element within each parent `flex` container to manipulate.

```css
form {
  display: flex;
}

label {
  flex-grow: 1;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="t1">String</label><input type="text" id="t1">
</form>

<form>
  <label for="t2">Long string</label><input type="text" id="t2">
</form>

<form>
  <label for="t3">The longest string</label><input type="text" id="t3">
</form>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cyhgk9j2/1/

Answer (score 0):

As you are using bootstrap you can use `col-md-4` and `col-md-8` so that elements will be aligned vertically. And for text+Input to be in the middle you can use `text-align: center;`

I have made an example here. [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wghbtsfq/)